# Testing unwriteable fields

Tags: apex, unit-test

I am trying to write tests for code that depends on the `Status` picklist field of `EmailMessage` objects. The `Status` field is **unwriteable**.

For testing purposes, I have been able to create an 'EmailMessage' object with a specific `Status` value, but am unable to alter it after that. I really need to test how other objects react to a change in `Status` of these `EmailMessage` objects and wonder what are the patterns for these situations where the actual fields are unwriteable after construction?

As an aside, I thought I'd mention that I was surprised that the values for these fields were *numbers* that must map to the actual values shown for the picklist ('New', 'Read' etc).

Many thanks

Comment: How about using an sObject Wrapper with instance variables for the unwriteable fields and getters/setters for the writable sObject fields. You can then write your test using the wrappers.

Comment: Can you experiment with tricks from this question to see if you can cheat in the test? http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/62/unit-testing-code-which-has-logic-around-the-createddate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wrapper pattern could provide a handy solution

```
Public with sharing class EmailMessageWrapper{

EmailMessage emailMsg;

Public EmailMessageWrapper(){
this.emailMsg = new EmailMessage();
}

// instance variable for immutable fields
Public String status { get ; set; }

Public String writeAbleField ( get { return        
emailMsg.WriteableField; } set { 
this.writeAbleField= value;} ) //check syntax

}
```

You can then use this wrapper for doing your tests, wrap results of soql queries before returning to processing methods.

Answer (score 0):

I am 99 % that this method Test.loadData would solve that problem.

Comment: Test.loadData lets you write into immutable fields at load, however I don't reckon it will allow their manipulation as part of the test. (Compile time failure writing to for eg CreatedDate as part of the Test, although I could initialise it at load)

Comment: You are right :)

Answer (score 0):

To get the code coverage for the unwriteable fields in an Apex Test Method you can
Create test record using JSON (only in case when you are not performing any DML on that object)

```
Contact con = new Contact();
con.LastName ='Test';
String contactJSON = JSON.serialize(new List<Contact >{con}, false);

Account acc = (Account) JSON.deserialize('{"Contacts" : ' + contactJSON + ', "Name" :"Test" }', Account .class);
```

**Here the Contacts is related List which is not writeable in apex test class**