# Testing time-based batch class

Tags: apex, batch

I have a batch process that closes cases after 30 days of inactivity. Is it possible to  write test code that would create a case that is over 30 days old?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not without request modifiable audit fields (not recommended). Instead, make the "days older than" variable so it can be set by the test method:

```
global class CloseOldCases implements Database.batchable<Case> {
    global static Integer daysOlderThan;

    static {
        daysOlderThan = 30;
    }

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        DateTime searchDate = System.Now().addDays(-daysOlderThan);
        return Database.getQueryLocator([Select Id From Case Where LastModifiedDate < :searchDate]);
    }
    // Rest of code here
}
```

Construct your instance, call Test.startTest, call Database.executeBatch, set daysOlderThan to -1, create a case, then call Test.stopTest to execute your batch.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [Unit testing code which has logic around the CreatedDate](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/62/unit-testing-code-which-has-logic-around-the-createddate) where SObjects loaded via `JSON.deserialize` or via `Test.loadData` can have a specific (e.g. in the past) CreatedDate set.

I assume the same applies to fields like LastModifiedDate that your logic may be based upon.