# Finding how to cover List Assignment in VF Controller test class

Tags: visualforce, unit-test

I have the following code and pages that I inherited and needed to create a test class for, so far I have managed to cover most of the controller, but am stuck on the last part.

**Visualforce page**

```
<apex:page docType="html-5.0" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" cache="false" controller="TypeControllerNew2" standardStylesheets="false" >

<body>

   <outputPanel style="padding: 15px;">
         <a href="/apex/CaseList?fcf=00B21000000UI5I" class="alert-link">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Estimate of Non-Primary Charges</a>
                <!-- <label>Estimate of Non-Primary Charges</label> -->
            <apex:chart height="380" width="400" data="{!CaseCharges}">
                  <apex:legend position="right"/>
                  <apex:axis type="Numeric" position="bottom" fields="count" title="Case Record Count" minimum="0" maximum="10" />
                  <apex:axis type="Category" position="left" fields="typ" title="Case Type" />
                <apex:barSeries title="In Progress Cases" orientation="horizontal" gutter="10" axis="bottom" xField="count" yField="typ" colorsProgressWithinSeries="true" colorset="red, green, yellow, black, white, orange" >
                   <apex:chartTips height="20" width="120" />
                </apex:barSeries>

           </apex:chart>
           <apex:dataTable value="{!CaseCharges}" var="ty">
               <apex:column headerValue="Case Type" value="{!ty.typ}"/>
               <apex:column headerValue="Number of Cases" value="{!ty.count}"/>
           </apex:dataTable>
      </outputPanel>
</body>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public with sharing class TypeControllerNew2 {

     public class CaseCharges {

     public Integer count {get; set;}
     public String typ {get; set; }
     public CaseCharges(String typ, Integer count) {
         this.count = count;
         this.typ = typ;
     }
 }

public CaseCharges[] getCaseCharges() {
     @testVisible CaseCharges[] charges = new CaseCharges[] {};

   for (AggregateResult ar : [SELECT COUNT(id) cn, Type tp 
                              FROM Case 
                              WHERE Status!='Closed' AND Quotation__c!= NULL 
                              AND (Quotation_Approved__c=NULL OR Quotation_Approved__c='No') 
                              AND CreatedDate = Last_Month 
                              GROUP BY Type])
   {
     charges.add(new CaseCharges (
     (String) ar.get('tp'),
     (Integer) ar.get('cn')
     ));
   }
    return charges;
 }
}
```

**Test Class**

```
    @isTest 
    public class TypeControllerNew2_Test {

        public static User UserRecord;

        Static {
            userRecord = WSC_DummyDataCreatorTEST.getUser(); 
            System.debug('userRecord.ContactId-------'+userRecord.ContactId);
            System.debug('userRecord.Id----------'+userRecord.Id);    
        }   

       static testMethod void typeController2Test(){
       List<Case> caseList = WSC_DummyDataCreatorTEST.createCases(5, userRecord.Id, 'In Progress');
       Datetime myDateTime = Datetime.now().addDays(-25);
       for (case c : caseList){
       c.Quotation__c = 100.00;
       Test.setCreatedDate(c.Id, myDateTime);
       c.Quotation_Approved__c = 'No';
       c.type = 'Metering';
       System.assertNotEquals(Null, c.Quotation__c);
       system.assertNotEquals('Yes', c.Quotation_Approved__c);
       system.assertNotEquals('Closed', c.Status);
       system.assertNotEquals(Null, c.Type);
   }

   update caseList;


            PageReference graph2Page = Page.Sample_VF_CaseGraph2;
            Test.setCurrentPage(graph2Page);

            TypeControllerNew2 tcNew2Test = new TypeControllerNew2();
            TypeControllerNew2.CaseCharges myInnerClass = new TypeControllerNew2.CaseCharges('New',2);
            system.assertEquals('New', myInnerClass.typ);
            system.assertEquals(2, myInnerClass.count);

           tcNew2Test.getCaseCharges();


        }
    }
```

**Code Coverage**
[image]

Comment: Does query inside for loop return value? Put a debug statement and check.

Comment: Will the createCases method automatically create case that satisfies the following condition : Quotation__c is not null and case is created in last month?

Comment: Yes, I made sure that createCases Method will have Quotation__c with a value, as it will create the case at runtime then the creation date will be within the last month.

Comment: I dont think runtime creation of the case will return the case in last_month.you might have to explicitly specify the createddate  in test class.

Comment: Createddate is not a field that can be set even in test classes on testing that, which does not surprise me as it is a system field.

Comment: you can set that from spring '16 and the below answer specifies the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `getCaseCharges()` the SOQL WHERE clause includes `AND CreatedDate = Last_Month`.
To set this you need to use `Test.setCreatedDate(recordId, createdDatetime)` that was introduced in Spring '16.

See [Unit testing code which has logic around the CreatedDate](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/102858/102)

Comment: Ok, so updated the test class as above, but still need to pass the case list into the section that I can't cover.

Comment: @DaveHumm I see in your code that you set the createddate to 5 days ago. You should move it back to the previous month. Otherwise the test case will only pass for certain days of the month.

Comment: You could also add assertions just after setting the create date for the other criteria that the SOQL requires. E.g. `System.assertNotEquals(null, c.Quotation__c);`

Comment: ok will try doing that - never had much time to learn Apex before getting stuck with this exercise.

Comment: Ok, so added all criteria to test class and assertions to check them, the updated the case list after the loop to try and ensure the data is there but still not getting the coverage of that last section of code in the controller

Comment: @DaveHumm The section shown in read in the coverage results? Try adding temp `System.assert(false, 'bang');` statements both within the loop and immediately after it. Then examine the debug log when the test fails. It might provide more clues as to why the SOQL query is returning no results in the test case.