# Deserialize History record with read-only fields?

Tags: apex, json, sobject

I'm trying to serialize, then deserialize an `AccountHistory` record. However, whenever I include a read-only field, such as `NewValue`, in the JSON, when I try to deserialize the record, I get this error:

> System.UnexpectedException: Salesforce System Error: 158360809-105080 (2033965611) (2033965611)

Heres the code I'm working with:

```
AccountHistory history = [SELECT Id FROM AccountHistory WHERE Id = '017c000009RmtOFAAZ' LIMIT 1];  
AccountHistory historyWithValue = [SELECT Id, NewValue FROM AccountHistory WHERE Id = '017c000009RmtOFAAZ' LIMIT 1];

String historyString = JSON.serialize(history);

SObject someObj = (sObject)JSON.deserialize(historyString, sObject.class); // Works 
AccountHistory someHistory = (AccountHistory)JSON.deserialize(historyString, AccountHistory.class); // Works 

String historyValueString = JSON.serialize(historyWithValue);

SObject anotherObj = (sObject)JSON.deserialize(historyValueString, sObject.class); // Fails
AccountHistory anotherHistory = (AccountHistory)JSON.deserialize(historyValueString, AccountHistory.class); // Fails
```

How can I deserialize JSON data which includes a record with read-only fields?

---

I know there's a method of using JSON to set the CreatedDate on records for test contexts, which is a read-only field, so there must be some solution. As [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/88/10382) states:

> This doesn't enforce the normal read-only field attributes that prevent you from setting a createdDate value.

However, this does not seem to be the case for other object fields. For example, this code works:

```
String someJson = '{"AccountHistory":{"CreatedDate":"2017-11-07T15:56:30.000+0000"}}';
AccountHistory history = (AccountHistory)JSON.deserialize(someJson, AccountHistory.class); // Works
```

But this code causes a Salesforce exception:

```
String someJson = '{"AccountHistory":{"NewValue":"SomeValue"}}';
AccountHistory history = (AccountHistory)JSON.deserialize(someJson, AccountHistory.class); // Fails
```

Trying to update either of these fields through a constructor causes this exception:

```
new AccountHistory(NewValue = DateTime.now(), CreatedDate = DateTime.now());
```

> Field is not writeable: AccountHistory.NewValue
>
> Field is not writeable: AccountHistory.CreatedDate

The error message for both fields is the same, however, the behavior of the fields vary when it comes to `JSON` methods.

---

Trying to use `Test.LoadData` also fails with the same exception type. This was tested using this `.csv` file:

```
Field,OldValue,NewValue,AccountId
Name,SomeTest,AnotherTest,001c000001GWSaL
```

And this snippet in my `@testSetup` method:

```
Test.loadData(Schema.SObjectType.AccountHistory.getsObjectType(), 'ActivityHistoryTestData');
```

> System.UnexpectedException: Salesforce System Error: 797046050-85268 (-725019502) (-725019502)

---

The context behind this question involves creating test `AccountHistory` records. Since the `OldValue` and `NewValue` fields are not writeable, and Field History tracking is disabled in test contexts, I'm left with few options for writing a test class. I've already refactored a number of functions to allow raw data to be passed to them, allowing me to test them without requiring any history records. However, I'd still like to be able to test some other methods to obtain full coverage.

My solution to this problem was to create json test data, and then deserialize the data into history records, or at least sObjects. However, I've run into some trouble with the conversion from a string into the object.

Comment: Have you tried `Test.loadData`?

Comment: Sadly that also fails to insert the records. The error provided is also a Salesforce system error, but has a different set of numbers with it. Doesn't seem to matter much, since it fails right out of the gate.

Comment: Json.deserialize certainly works with read only fields as I use that all the time to mock formula fields and system audit fields; the issue is more with `someSobjectHistory` records

Comment: @battery.cord  What is the field that you are changing? Maybe this field has some value which causes the deserialization error

Comment: oh, I see it doesn't depend on the field

Comment: @battery.cord in the data setup method, you can simply update the records in order to create the history records. Did you try that?

Comment: @KiranMachhewar: I have tried that, this doesn't work

Comment: @KiranMachhewar in test context no real commit to database happens, so no history records are created

Comment: @Patlatus That's bummer, I was not aware of that. That means code dependent of History records cannot be tested? I hope someone has solution to this.

Comment: As a note, using `Approval.Lock` or `Approval.Unlock` does create a relevant history method, while other DML operations do not cause a history record to be created.

Comment: Looks like it is possible to create history records for custom objects using `Test.LoadData`. Note: there are issues with this approach. You can learn more from [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/191666/10382).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the problem is that `JSON` uses strict concrete type definition.

You can't write something like

```
AccountHistory history = (AccountHistory)JSON.deserialize('{"NewValue":a}', AccountHistory.class);
```

because that would raise exception

> System.JSONException: Unexpected character ('a' (code 97)): expected a
>   valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
>   at [line:1, column:14]

So this means you can put values for numbers, strings, arrays, objects (maps), booleans or `null`.

While `EntityHistory` [`NewValue` field has type "anyType" in SOAP](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_entityhistory.htm)

[image]

So when Apex tries to deserialize JSON and put any concrete value to `anyType` field it fails, since types may not match, the actual type of this `anyType` field depends on `Field` column, but Apex translator is unfortunately unable to resolve this reference and detect that `Field` column value is `Name`, so string values are correct for `NewValue` even if you specify value for the `Field` column:

```
AccountHistory history = (AccountHistory)JSON.deserialize('{"Field":"Name", "NewValue":"a"}', AccountHistory.class);
```

> System.UnexpectedException: Salesforce System Error: 1492486810-150788
>   (2033965611) (2033965611)

The only value which satisfies `anyType` type is `null`, so when you give `null` value it doesn't fail:

```
AccountHistory history = (AccountHistory)JSON.deserialize('{"Field":"Name", "NewValue":null}', AccountHistory.class);
```

> Success

So I see the following options:

1. Use only `null` values for `NewValue` and `OldValue` fields
2. Try to use `Test.isRunningTest()` and mock some dependent logic with it.
3. Try to use `Test.createStub()` method and `StubProvider` interface implementation to mock dependent logic with it.

[Mocking framework with Stub API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_stub_api.htm) is a wonderful feature which I have never heard before and which I have found about very-very recently. This is ability to mock tests with stub interface

It is now possible to create sophisticated [stub interface](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_interface_System_StubProvider.htm#apex_interface_System_StubProvider) implementation and use it with method [Test.createStub](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_test.htm#apex_System_Test_createStub) to avoid using of `Test.isRunningTest()`.

=================

Augmenting research results from answers to similar questions.

[This answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/191666/3716) suggests there to use `Test.loadData` but it is clear that using using of `Test.loadData` for `AccountHistory` object  clearly raises internal error exception, for all cases

with `NewValue` or `OldValue`

```
AccountId,Field,OldValue,NewValue
001b0000008g2iPAAQ,Name,a,b
001b0000008g2iQAAQ,Name,c,d
```

[image]

with no `NewValue` or `OldValue` column

```
AccountId,Field
001b0000008g2iPAAQ,Name
001b0000008g2iQAAQ,Name
```

with empty values of those fields

```
AccountId,Field,OldValue,NewValue
001b0000008g2iPAAQ,Name
001b0000008g2iQAAQ,Name
```

[In this answer it is suggested](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/4011/3716) to split processing of records into several parts.

1. Have a DAO method which retrieves the actual records similar to `queryDatabase` in quoted answer
2. Have a method which converts records into strings or objects
3. Have a method which processes strings or objects converted from records.

You can test the first method that it returns zero records in test context.
You can test the second method that if you build records without NewValue or OldValue it converts them correctly.
You can test the actual logic passing string or object instead of real records.

Also as the last resort you can try to use `SeeAllData=true` like it is suggested in [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/139242/3716).

Comment: This is really interesting - I'll try writing some code with this in mind on Monday and see what happens!

Comment: @battery.cord I have updated my answer augmenting research results from answers to similar questions.  Probably you might try to combine all of these to get it work. So you might use `Test.isRunningTest()` or `Test.createStub()` to mock some method or just split your code to three parts: querying records, processing records to models, and actual logic to be performed on models, not records. This way you will gain 100% coverage testing each part separately.

Comment: ApexMocks is a framework on top of stub interface and my preferred solution

Comment: Specifically, the code I need to test is sorting and creating wrapper data from the query result. I think if I switched the parameter for the sorting to another wrapper, so I can provide custom values through a stub or etc, that would let me provide coverage. Stubbing without a wrapper class seems pointless, since I won't be able to create the records at all, and If I'm using a wrapper, I could just create the data in the test. I guess I don't really see a benefit from using a stub in this situation, since I can't create then return history records from the stub.

Comment: so if you need to test sorting and creating wrapper then it really doesn't make sense to user stub, you could just create wrapper and pass it to the method you are testing. So are you able to get 100% coverage?

Comment: Refactoring is always a possibility, especially when the changes would be internal to the controller. I'm able to get full coverage, but I wanted to see if there was a way for me to create this data inside the test, but that does not seem to be a possibility, in any regard. A part of me still thinks there's some way to get the JSON method to work, but there's likely an internal field used to determine the type that we can't access, making it pointless to try. On to refactoring!